# How do the mirrors in lasers resist destruction by the laser?

Tags: optics, material-science, reflection, laser

Are lasers limited by the quality of the mirrors they use? How are the mirrors used in a laser not destroyed or ignited in the process? Are mirrors just really resistant to light? Is the mirror user in a laser same as the silicon dioxide in my windows?

Comment: they have extremely high reflectivity so not a lot of energy is absorbed by the mirrors for one thing.

Comment: @DakkVader that's the answer to the question. I recommend you write that up

Comment: Having blown up a few mirrors in my time, they aren't perfect, just usually good enough!

Comment: Is there some kind of new material we can use so they never blow up?

Comment: Numbers - no, they usual cause is either an imperfection in the coatings, a scratch, or dust on the surface. All can locally cause fields and absorption high enough to exceed the design limits.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.  This is very actively discouraged as it leaves questions without a proper answer.  Please write a proper answer.

Comment: @KFGauss StephenG I write this as a comment because i suspected that this is the major answer for what the OP is asking about, but i was not sure if it was the only mechanic behind it and i didn't have time to investigate it further as i was at work. Now i see that solomon slow beat me to it and that there is no point for me to write my own answer. Glad i could help at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lasers use *[first surface mirrors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_surface_mirror)*. The "glass" substrate is not exposed to the laser light (except, for the exit mirror, which transmits only a small fraction of the light from the resonant cavity.)

The actual reflective surface is a [thin film coating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichroic_filter) that is extremely efficient at the laser's wavelength (again, except for the exit mirror, which transmits a *controlled* small fraction...).

The "glass" used in the exit mirror and, in any lenses, often is a specialized material (in some cases, it may be a single crystal of the material) that is extremely transparent to the laser wavelength.

---

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_damage_threshold

Answer (score 1):

I initially wrote this as a comment but I'll write it as an answer as well for the sake of it.

Mirrors used in laser cavities have extremely high reflectivities and thus a very small portion of the total cavity energy is absorbed in the mirrors as a large portion of what is not reflected is instead transmitted as the output. There are other elements in the cavity that might need active cooling, such as the gain medium etc.